How to import .OUT file created by C program into RStudio
I'm running Hazard function code which is written C program. In the end the C program provides a a.OUT file which contains text and some tables information. The table should be imported as a data frame in RStudio to build graphs.
The sample of this a.OUT file looks like "
 >; @!6Żu @\* u%  @#3 ir?( r            ?Q  Q @ > t sP@ $    @ V( (@ K /   @   6٨A      @%* n  x@ ń . F@\*&d \(@" _Fr+ ?( r      

As the information looks like SAS transport file I tried using write.xpt from heaven, but no luck. Can anyone please guide on how to read this type of file in RStudio?
Thanks in advance!!!!

That looks like a binary file.

That's a binary file. It's not text. What produces that file? Is it the C compiler, or the output of running your executable? On *nix platforms, C/C++ compilers produce an object file with a .out extension, which is then provided to the linker to use to produce the executable itself. It's of no use to anything else but the linker or a debugger.

i see many words in the question that seem to be computer science related. my knowledge is not enough to comprehend what is OP intents. can someone at least do a markup of the question, so it will be clear that person using some IT machinery to do something?

@KenWhite the .out files I know are executables created by the linker, not fed into it.

@Gerhardh: Oops! Of course you're right. I've got it reversed. Haven't done C anything on *nix for ages, and apparently didn't think long enough before writing.  The .o files are by the compiler, the .out are the executables. Still means they're not useful for importing to rstudio, though. :-) Thanks for the correction.

Does not look like a SAS transport file.  Such files start with HEADER RECORD*******LIB

Would you mind to share the whole .OUT file? You can create it with some arbitrary/fake data. It will help to find a solution to your problem. If there is tabular data in the file, you can read it in using read.table(), if that's binary file, use readBin() and manipulate the data.
